# AutoCompleteTextView not showing keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to implement a custom `SearchView` that shows a dropdown list with the possible matches.

To do this, I firstly defined a custom layout:

**customsearchview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
     >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/imagebutton_selector"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I created a custom menu to show this layout in `ActionBar` when search button is selected.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/editor_button_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/customsearchview"
/>
```

The custom layout is shown properly, but the soft keyboard is not shown unless I touch the `AutoCompleteTextView`. How is it possible to show it?

Comment: You do know that SearchView has built in support for [custom search suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I also know that something like http://drzon.net/content/images/2013/Nov/gmail.png can't be done with default `SearchView`.

Comment: Uh, yes it can - the icon shown on the left is `SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1` .

Comment: It's not made with a `SearchView`, it's not possible, as stated in this tutorial http://drzon.net/how-to-create-a-clearable-autocomplete-dropdown-with-autocompletetextview/

Comment: It is 100% possible with a SearchView as I've done it. Whether it is less work to work around the system and build custom components than use the built in tools is debatable and depends more on what format your data is in (as the Android approach assumes your search suggestions are bound to a Content Provider).

Comment: @ianhanniballake if it's possible could you make an answer with some guidelines? I'll be very glad to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<requestFocus />` tag below `AutoCompleteTextView`